# Failed executing DbCommand because timeout expired .net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My goal is to provide simple API to retrieve data from `Payments` (~400 rows) table which consists 5 columns.

```
Payment: Id (int),
PaymentsNumber (tinyint),
Rate (decimal(18,2)),
ProductType (tinyint),
ClientClubType (tinyint).
```

Users can make posts request with with the request params of (should return ~12 rows):

```
PaymentsRequest 
{
    public int? PaymentsNumber { get; set; }
    public byte? ProductType { get; set; }
    public byte? ClientClubType { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF-Core:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(...),optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.CommandTimeout(60)));

public async Task<IEnumerable<Payments>> GetPaymentsAsync(PaymentsRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<Payments> query = this._context.Set<Payments>();
    query = query.Where(filter => 
                        (request.ClientClubType == null || filter.ClientClubType == request.ClientClubType) &&
                        (request.ProductType == null || filter.ProductType == request.ProductType) &&
                        (request.PaymentsNumber == null || filter.PaymentsNumber == request.PaymentsNumber));

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

On azure application insights I can see 2 consecutive logs, caused by the same exception:

1. Log1: Failed executing DbCommand.
2. Log2: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The Log1 is (while there is no need to write here the log2):

> Failed executing DbCommand (65,238ms)
>   [Parameters=[@__request_ClientClubType_0='?' (Size = 1) (DbType =
>   Byte), @__request_ProductType_1='?' (Size = 1) (DbType = Byte)],
>   CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
>
> SELECT [p].[Id],
>   [p].[ClientClubType], [p].[PaymentsNumber], [p].[ProductType],
>   [p].[Rate] FROM [Payments] AS [p] WHERE (([p].[ClientClubType] =
>   @__request_ClientClubType_0) AND @__request_ClientClubType_0 IS NOT
>   NULL) AND (([p].[ProductType] = @__request_ProductType_1) AND
>   @__request_ProductType_1 IS NOT NULL)

**My application is a .net core 3.0 application deployed on azure linux webapp.**

The issue only occurs from production not every time and I can not reconstruct the issue from MSSMS.
Any idea?

UPDATE:

After @panagiotis-kanavos commented, I've updated my code to:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(...),optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.CommandTimeout(60)));

public async Task<IEnumerable<Payments>> GetPaymentsAsync(PaymentsRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<Payments> query = this._context.Payments;
    query = query.Where(filter => 
                        (filter.ClientClubType == request.ClientClubType) &&
                        (filter.ProductType == request.ProductType) &&
                        (filter.PaymentsNumber == request.PaymentsNumber));

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: The problem is quite clear: `Failed executing DbCommand (65,238ms)`. The default execution timeout is 60 seconds, your command is taking longer than that.

Comment: This is only *part* of the exception, not the exception itself. I bet the exception message says there was a timeout

Comment: As for why this takes so long, it could be missing indexes, concurrency conflicts with other queries, problems with the query itself (catch-all queries are bad and not needed at all with LINQ). Most likely, the query locks too many rows because of those `NULL`s, causing conflicts with other queries that try to touch the same table. Perhaps a long-running transaction too?

Comment: You can add conditions dynamically with `if(someParam!=null){ query=query.Where(r=>r.field==param);}`. This sequence of `Where`s is equivalent to an `AND`. If you don't need a parameter, just don't add the condition

Comment: The big problem with catch-all queries is that the server caches the execution plan created for the first execution. If that query had all nulls, effectively selecting everything, the server would create an execution plan that would do a table scan, even if there are indexes on the columns. It doesn't need them after all. Subsequent queries would still use that table scan, even if they needed an index. That's a problem with the query, not the server.

Comment: That table scan now, takes S(hared) locks on all rows. That means that any query that wants to *update*, has to wait for the other transaction to complete. If your code opens and holds a transaction explicitly (which it shouldn't do with any ORM), the locks may remain for a long time. This increases conflicts and blocking a *lot*

Comment: If you use database transactions to implement "Business transactions per request" or Unit-Of-Work, which you don't need to, your queries end up blocking each other. You don't need to because ORMs *cache* changes and only persist them atomically, in a single batch,  when a call to `SaveChanges` is made. You already have a UoW, you don't need DB transactions to implement it (which can't do so anyway)

Comment: Or you may be reading data before updating the rows, thus leading to a long transaction. The fix to this is *not* transactions. It's optimistic concurrency or idempotent operations. For example, `UPDATE Accounts SET BALANCE=BALANCE+100` works no matter what the initial balance is. You don't need to read the balance in a transaction before saving the new value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos regarding your comment on UOF, how did you figure out that I'm using UOF?

Comment: WIth such a small table, the only way to get 60 seconds of blocking is a long running transaction *and* updates. Queries that just select don't block each other. DbContext itself *is* a UoW - all changes are persisted at once when SaveChanges is called, so it's not that either. So there has to be a long running transaction. Those are typically used when EF Core/ORM usage is broken by bad "generic" repositories, eg a "generic" `Insert` that immediatelly calls `SaveChanges`. Once you do that, UoW is gone. The only way to get it back is the long transaction

Comment: And once you do that, you get into blocking. There's no need for a "generic" repository or extra UoW. Most ORMs work disconnected. All are *already* generic - the "generic" implementations simply defer to DbSet calls for example.

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). It explains those things in a better way and also explains how that `Insert` or `Update` found in "generic" repositories can easily run a dozen `DELETE` queries too

Comment: Hey @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried all of your suggestion and the problem still occurs, see updated question :)

Comment: can you install sp_whoisactive and check how many transactions you've got while your query runs?

Comment: you should involve dba to monitor SQL for deadlocks. This should give you what causes sql query to lock when selecting from Payments. However 400 records is not a big deal. I've seen how parallel `update` queries running on different rows in the approx 1000 rows caused deadlocks without `with rowlock` hint. It was because MSSQL was starting update one row with **table** lock.

Comment: how does ur connectionstring look like ?

Comment: @Thomas `Server=1.1.1.1;Database=foo;UserId=foo;Password=foo`

Comment: The datatype of PaymentsNumber on your database and in your request object doesn't match. I had a performance issue with varchar columns, because the EF Core converted the C# type string to nvarchar hence the SQL server had to cast all the values again from nvarchar to varchar (for each effected row) which led to long running queries even for small result sets. You could use the SQL Server Profiler to sniff the generated and executed query and analyse it for performance issues.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  When testing in SSMS, did you use the same isolation level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your timeout is 60 seconds this could be increased.  It's usually not a good idea to do this as it will hide other issues.
- If the table has lots of writes, or something has a long running transaction, it can block/contend with your query.
- If you query is part of a larger begin transaction - end transaction sequence of SQL operations, it may be blocked by other open transactions
- Same as last one - If multiple calls are made at the same time/nearly the same time to this query it could slow down processing of each query.  I've seen this where a web front end populates a screen of 20 lines of data where each line is an different call to the same web-api endpoint for the same type of data.  For example, getting the monthly transaction dollar total for each of the last 12 months.